# Request did not match any routes

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, routes

I suddenly started getting this error while testing another problem. Whenever I try to run my code locally I get a blank page. In my log, I see that "Request did not match any routes"

```
    app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "areaRoute",
                template: "{area:exists}/{controller}/{action}/{id?}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Abstract}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```

Up until now, I wasn't having a problem and my code would use the areaRoute to open the Dashboard. Now it's ignoring the routes altogether.

```
    [Area(Consts.Area)]
public class Dashboard : Controller
{
    private DashboardService _service;
    public Dashboard(DashboardService service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }

    [Authorize(Roles = "admin")]
    public ActionResult InternalDashboard()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

This is the controller where I'm getting the problem. It's inside an area called AbstractReport. I've tried using MapAreaRoute as well as only having one route to see if it would pick it up. MapAreaRoute didn't work and I get the same behavior no matter how many routes I have. This code does work on the server the problem is only happening locally. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to **specify the default area, controller and action name** in the first area route.

For aspnet core 2 your default route would be something like this:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
     name: "areaRoute",
     template: "{area:exists}/{controller}/{action}/{id?}"
     defaults: new {
         controller = nameof(Dashboard),
         area = Consts.Area,
         action = nameof(Dashboard.InternalDashboard)
     });
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm now being redirected to my specified LoginPath but my url is http://localhost:55730/AbstractReport/Dashboard/InternalDashboard/Account/Login/?ReturnUrl=%2FAbstractReport%2FDashboard%2FInternalDashboard ...its taggig the defaults to the beginning of the url. shouldn'tt the default route be used on the redirect?

Comment: The login redirection path is defined by autorization scheme, if you have not changed the default authorization configuration the same login path is used for all the site including areas it is not relative to the area